# Cartthrob gift certificates shipping cost

Tags: cartthrob, giftcertificates

I use cartthrob with cartthrob gift certificates, but i have a problem with the shipping cost.

When a user buys a gift card shipping is included in the total. Since the giftcard is sent via email, I don't want shipping added for it.

I would like it to work like this:

- When the user only has a gift card in the cart we don't want to charge for shipping
- When the user has other products, the shipping should be charged

I hope someone can help me with this problem

Answer (score 1):

Inside your {exp:cartthrob_gift_certificates:add_to_cart_form} add the parameter shipping_exempt="yes"

By adding that parameter, the gift certificate will not be factored in when calculating the shipping costs.